# how to deal with numerous elements in a condition?

Tags: python

I sometimes need to use many elements in a condition, all being the same kind

```
args = list()
if "a" not in args or "b" not in args or "c" not in args:
    print("something is missing")
```

This gets complicated when the number of elements to test gets large. I tried to combine them in a list but the end result is ugly:

```
args = list()
for what in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    if what not in args:
        print("something is really missing")
        break
```

What would be a pythonic way to code this kind of situation (several components, all the same, to an `if`)?

Comment: `if not all(x in args for x in "abc"):`? Or you could make them sets and use [`if not set(args).issuperset("abc"):`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if not all(arg in args for arg in ("a", "b", "c")):
```

Also, consider raising an error, rather than printing a message.

Comment: Yes, I will raise one in the real program. This one-liner construction is very useful, I will have to keep it in mind (though I favor more explicit code, this is a trauma from my Perl times where everything started OK, then came "simplification" and "one-liners" and the code started its own life)

Comment: @WoJ if that's your preference, there was nothing wrong with your existing construction!

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my comment. I was looking exactly for what you gave in the answer, I just did not know how to build it (but having seen it several times I knew that the construction existed)). In general I just prefer to be careful when packing too much into one-liners because I do not understand what I wrote after some time. Your answer was perfect, though, and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Using sets will work :

```
args = list(....)
if set(["a","b","c"]).issubset(args):
    print("something is really missing")
```

This works if the ordering does not matter - i.e. a,b,c can exist in any order in args, and if there can be other things in args (other than a,b,c)

Comment: That should be `set("abc")` or `set(("a", "b", "c"))`, and you're missing quotes